# Core Data: Poor performance fetching with a relationship count predicate

Tags: core-data

I'm fetching a few thousand objects from Core Data and I only want to return those that have at least 1 object related to it.

When I use a predicate similar to the following, it takes a very long time to fetch the objects. Around 5-8 seconds:

```
NSPredicate(format: "relationName.@count > 0")
```

Is there a more efficient way of performing this fetch, or should I cache the value in the object for fast lookup (i.e. a `hasRelatedObjects` attribute).

If caching is the best route, I don't believe it trivial. If I modify my `Tag` object for example, in the `willSave` I can grab the relation count and store it in my new attribute. However if a related object adds the tag to itself on it's side of the relationship, the `Tag` object never changes and therefore the `willSave` won't get called.

How can I make sure that whether you call `myTag.addRelatedObject(obj)` (`myTag` object is updated) or `myObj.addRelatedTag(myTag)` (`myObj` is updated), that the value is cached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's just do a little bit of prototyping to see what that fetch is doing.  I assume you are using an SQLite store.

I hacked a quick model, similar to what you described.

I defined an Entity that had a to-many relationship to Subentity, where that Subentity had a to-one inverse relationship.

Now, I was testing in the simulator, so I created a database with 10mm entities.  Each time a new entity was created, it had about a 2% chance of having at least one subentity created for it.  Each entity so selected randomly got between 1 and 10 subentities.

Thus, I ended up with a database with 10,000,000 Entity objects, and 1,101,223 Subentity objects, with 199,788 Entity objects having at least one Subentity in its relationship.

---

For the most simple fetch request (the same as the one in your example), we get this code...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subentities.@count != 0"];
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
```

and the generated SQL, along with how much time it took to do the fetch.

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSUBCOUNT
    FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(t1.Z_PK) FROM ZSUBENTITY t1
    WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t1.ZENTITY) ) <> ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 17.9598s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 17.9657s for 199788 rows.
```

If you know much about SQL, you can see that the query is anything but optimal.  There is way too much going on underneath on both tables.

If we simply add a cache for the number of relationships, we get this result (note the table is not indexed on count).

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subcount != 0"];
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
```

we then get these results...

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSUBCOUNT
    FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZSUBCOUNT <> ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 1.5795s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 1.5838s for 199788 rows.
```

Now, let's see what happens if we index the `subcount` field.

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSUBCOUNT
    FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZSUBCOUNT <> ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 1.5749s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 1.5788s for 199788 rows.
```

Hmmm.  Not much better.  What if we change the predicate slightly...

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSUBCOUNT
    FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZSUBCOUNT > ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.7805s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.7843s for 199788 rows.
```

Now, that took half the time.  I'm not exactly sure why, because even if the slower path did two binary searches, there are no records with a value less than 0.

And, I'd expect a much better improvement, based on the fact that with sorted indexes, it should be able to do a binary search, which should be much better than half the speed of a complete linear scan.

Anyway, it does show that it can get faster than that.

Just to see what our lower bound is, we can do this...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Test"];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 199788;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
```

which gives these results, and about the best we can expect to grab that many records since it basically does no search.

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSUBCOUNT
    FROM ZENTITY t0  LIMIT 199788
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.1284s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.1364s for 199788 rows.
```

Now, if we only care about whether they are empty or not, and we don't care about the actual count, we can make our cached count be a boolean instead, which is always either 0 or 1.

By taking this approach, our fetch with predicate

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subcount > 0"];
```

yields

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSUBCOUNT
    FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZSUBCOUNT > ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.5312s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.5351s for 199788 rows.
```

Changing the predicate back to this

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subcount != 0"];
```

yields

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSUBCOUNT
    FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZSUBCOUNT <> ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 1.5619s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 1.5657s for 199788 rows.
```

And this one

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subcount == 1"];
```

yields

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZSUBCOUNT
    FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZSUBCOUNT = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.5332s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.5366s for 199788 rows.
```

So, there is still some meat on that bone, but I'll let you have **some** fun.

---

OK, so given that we want to cache the changes, how can we accomplish this?

Well, the easiest way is to just provide a custom method that gets used each time a relationship is changed.  However, it then requires that all changes go through that, and there's always the chance that some piece of code manipulates the object outside of the special API.

Well, one way to notice that the computed value needs to be update is when the object saves.  You can override `willSave` and make any necessary change there.  You could also observe the context-will-save notification and do the work in there.

To me, the main problem with that approach is that the "will save" notifications happen before validation and merging with the persistent store.  Either of these processes could change the data, and there are some tricky merge issues that could cause problems.

The only way to really ensure that validations and merging has been taken core of is by hooking into the validation phase.

Unfortunately, this approach is strongly discouraged by Apple documentation.  I have had good success with this pattern though.

```
- (BOOL)validateSubcount:(id*)ioValue error:(NSError**)outError
{
    NSUInteger computedValue = [*ioValue unsignedIntegerValue];
    NSUInteger actualValue = computedValue;

    NSString *key = @"subentities";
    if ([self hasFaultForRelationshipNamed:key]) {
        if (self.changedValues[@"subcount"]) {
            if (has_objectIDsForRelationshipNamed) {
                actualValue = [[self objectIDsForRelationshipNamed:key] count];
            } else {
                actualValue = [[self valueForKey:key] count];
            }
        }
    } else {
        actualValue = [[self valueForKey:key] count];
    }

    if (computedValue != actualValue) {
        *ioValue = @(actualValue);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This gets called automatically when saving, and you can call it manually (via validateValue:forKey:error:) from objects-did-change notification (or anyplace else for that matter) if you want more "frequent" consistency not just when saving.

---

On your question about changing the to-one relationship; core data will handle the inverse relationship properly.  Furthermore, all objects involved will have appropriate changes reflected.

Specifically, if you you change a subentity's to-one relationship.  You will now have three updated objects: the subentity itself, the entity that used to be at the other end of the relationship, and the entity that is now at the other end of the relationship.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for the in-depth information! Really useful. Struggling to figure out where the rest of that meat on the bone is though haha :-)

Comment: TL;DR - Could you add a summary on top?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have defined reverse relationships, right? So the `didSet` handler on your relationship should be called as well even it is changed from the other side.

Indeed, I think `willSave` should also be called. Did you verify that it isn't?